# Is it possible to make a check on a macro argument with the #if into the mcro function

Tags: c, macros

I want to develop a macro in this way

```
#define MACRO_TEST(a, MM, MN) \
#if MM == 1
    printf("MM "); \
#endif
#if MN == 1
    printf("MN "); \
#endif
    printf("%d\n",a);


main()
{
   MACRO_TEST(4, 1, 1); // output should be: MM MN 4
   MACRO_TEST(4, 1, 0); // output should be: MM 4
   MACRO_TEST(4, 0, 1); // output should be: MN 4
   MACRO_TEST(4, 0, 0); // output should be: 4
}
```

Is it possible to do that in C?

And what's the right way? because the above code generate a build errors

Comment: Remember that all arguments for a macro must be evaluable at compile-time.

Comment: Why use macros? It is silly

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `#if`, the classical `if` statement will work just fine.

Moreover, in your example it seems that the use of the macro is not really justified : why you don't use a simple function ?

```
void test(int a, int mm, int mn)
{
    if(mm == 1)
        printf("MM ");
    if(mn == 1)
       printf("MN ");
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return;
}
```

Comment: this is a running check and I want a preprocesser check

Comment: I'm missing a point: how can you evaluate `MM` and `MN` before the execution when they are set in your main ?

Comment: That what I m asking for

Comment: Then I suggest you rephrase your question.
You cannot evaluate `MM` or `MN` at compilation if they are set at execution. You are probably mixing up with `#ifdef` checks which ensure that you have defined a specific constant ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to give the compiler all its needed info and let it to optimize the if/else code for you.

```
#define MACRO_TEST(a, MM, MN) \
    do{                    \
        if (MM == 1)       \
            printf("MM "); \
        if (MN == 1)       \
            printf("MN "); \
        printf("%d\n",a);  \
    }while(0)
```

As long you provide constants literals to the MACRO_TEST arguments, you'll get what you want.

The hard way is to use the P99 Preprocessor macros: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#define MACRO_TEST(a, MM, MN)\
BOOST_PP_IF(MM, printf("MM ");, )\
BOOST_PP_IF(MN, printf("MN ");, )\
printf("%d\n",a);
```